# Can't run Minitest - Getting undefined class variable in MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd

I am trying to get my model testing up and running and am getting the error in my terminal

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized class variable @@current in MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
```

Here are my gems:

```
gem 'faker'

group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug'
gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
gem 'minitest-rails'
gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
gem 'minitest-colorize'
gem 'minitest-focus'
gem 'fabrication'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Any here is my user_test.rb file:

```
require "test_helper"

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

it "should create a user" do
@user = User.create!(:email => "user@gmail.com", :password => "xxxxxxxx",        :password_confirmation => "xxxxxxxx")
end

describe "should have a unique username" do
@user1 = Fabricate(:user, username: "bficho")
@user2 = Fabricate.build(:user, username: "bficho")
@user2.valid?.must_equal false
end

end
```

This is driving me nuts as I can't do much until I get my tests working!  Anyone else seeing this??

Answer (score 1):

Change your test like this:(According to [this](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/72))

```
require "test_helper"
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe MiniTest::Spec
 it "should create a user" do
  @user = User.create!(:email => "user@gmail.com", :password => "xxxxxxxx",        :password_confirmation => "xxxxxxxx")
 end

 it "should have a unique username" do
  @user1 = Fabricate(:user, username: "bficho")
  @user2 = Fabricate.build(:user, username: "bficho")
  @user2.valid?.must_equal false
 end
end
```

I think in your case, changing the second test case from `describe` to `it` might work

```
describe "should have a unique username" do
```

should be changed to

```
it "should have a unique username" do
```